# If I give sadaqah is that recorded for my father, given that he supports me?

Tags: sadaqah, deeds

I am a student supported by my father. I live in a different place from my parents. I was wondering if I give sadaqah would that good deed would be recorded for my father or for me?

Comment: Every good deed you do, is automatically recorded for your parents if they are/were muslim and had taught you to do good deeds.

Also in this case the money you will give sadaqah is also from him, so he will get reward, you don't need to worry.